# CSS Modules and hover css not working properly

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, webpack, css-modules

I created react web-app with custom build - everything built from scratch: webpack, webpack-server, typescript, image-loaders, css, scss, css-modules.
I have problem with CSS pseudo elements. Hover is not working properly.

```
 .image {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 10;
}

.image:hover{
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

link to live preview https://5c1a4a2b9db5a37380b6ebf0--practical-archimedes-b4d9da.netlify.com/

Im not sure whats going on. I would love to hear some pro tips from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as expected, this is not related to `css-modules` or `react`, this is how `CSS` works.

When the element is `hidden` it "loses" the hovered state, so it is switching back to `visible` (initial value for `visibility`) then again catches the hover event and so on. This is why it flickers.

What you can do is make it to `opacity:0`:

```
.image:hover{
  opacity:0;
}
```

Example with the differences:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.box {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.opacity:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.hidden:hover {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class=" box opacity ">Opacity</div>
  <div class="box hidden ">Visibility</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to solve the problem

```
.image {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 10;
}

   &:hover{
     visibility: hidden !important;
   }
```

Comment: Wrap &:hover inside .image